# equivalent of "ssh -c blowfish" for rsync?

Tags: ssh, rsync

What is the equivalent of doing

```
ssh -c blowfish
```

with `rsync` for fast block cipher if one wants to have faster transfer rates?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
rsync ... -e "ssh -c blowfish" ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Try: `rsync -e "ssh -c blowfish"`